# Add custom message to the plugins page of Wordpress

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'd like to add a banner at the top of the plugins page (where you update plugins) that reads "Please do not update plugins".

I know I can use the `admin_notices` hook to attach the message, but how do I make sure it only shows on the plugins page in the Wordpress admin?

Comment: Try [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function to get current screen (admin page) information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rilwis. `get_current_screen()` returns a page object, from which I can check its id, which I imagine is unique!

```
function dont_update_plugins() {
    $screen = get_current_screen(); 
    if($screen->id == "plugins"):?>
        <div class="updated">
            <h3><?php _e( 'Please do not update plugins!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></h3>
        </div>
    <?php endif; 
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'dont_update_plugins' );
```

Comment: ID's are always unique :-)